# Unrecognised database format in Visual Studio 2015 with MS Access Database in for C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I am facing this error.. I am using MS Office 2016 32-bit and Visual Studio 2015 Pro.

But when I connect to a MS Access database file from my Visual Studio project and access file extension is `.accdb`

I have also installed MS Access Database Engine 2010 32-bit, but it's not working. I have also configured it to 32-bit platform.

I have tried many times but it comes with this error.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Go to this link and download the file. Close your Visual Studio and then once the file was installed to your computer, re-open your Visual Studio and try to connect to the database again.